Two definitons of a pullback of a differential form
Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of spaces with admitting differential forms (e.g. real manifold, complex manifold, smooth algebraic variety, schemes). Let $\Omega^n_Y$ denote the sheaf of $n$-forms on $Y$.
When one speaks of a "pullback of a differential form," there are at least two possible interpretations. The first is the one from differential geometry: given a section on $\Omega^n_Y(U)$, we get a section on $\Omega^n_X(f^{-1}(U))$ defined locally by
$$g \; dy_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dy_n \mapsto (g \circ f) \; d(y_1 \circ f) \wedge \dots \wedge d(y_n \circ f).$$
This gives us a bona fide section of $\Omega^n_X$; using the chain rule, we can check this map respects the respective transition functions for $\Omega^{n}_Y$ and $\Omega^n_X$, and this is what most non-algebraic geometers seem to mean when referring to pullback of differential forms.
However, there is another common usage of the word "pullback": the canonical map on sections $H^0(Y, \Omega^n_Y) \to H^0(X, f^*\Omega^n_Y)$, or more generally $H^0(U, \Omega^n_Y) \to H^0(f^{-1}(U), f^*\Omega^n_Y).$ I really only know how describe this map affine-locally in the algebraic category. For example, if $X = \text{Spec } A$ and $Y = \text{Spec } B$ are $k$-varieties, then $\Omega_Y$ is the sheaf associated the module of Kähler differentials $\Omega_{B/k}$, and $f^*\Omega_Y$ is the sheaf associated to the $A$-module $A \otimes_B \Omega_{B/k}$. Then the map on sections is given locally by sending $\omega \in \Omega_{B/k}$ to $1 \otimes \omega \in A \otimes_B \Omega_{B/k}$.
These two definitions of pullback cannot be literally the same, since in general $f^*\Omega^n_Y \not \simeq \Omega^n_X$–the outputted sections live on entirely different sheaves. But I have deeply confused myself trying to think about how they are related and whether we can easily convert between the two versions. Is there something I am missing, or a better way of thinking about this? I worry because I cannot find any literature that seems to address this conflict, so I feel like there is some obvious thing that is being left unsaid.

You can’t use Kahler differentials in differential geometry, and in particular a lot of the constructions in algebraic geometry are analogues of things in geometry, but trying to actually use them will lead to issues. The map on cohomology in differential geometry is just $[\omega]\mapsto [f^*\omega]$, where we use your first definition.  This is also a different cohomology theory from the one encountered in algebraic geometry because it is entirely induced by the exterior derivative.

@Chris Does a pullback map on sections as in the second definition above even exist in general in the analytic setting?

It probably does, but using standard algebraic geometry for these types of questions is in general not fruitful, and I know of no results regarding that cohomology theory being applied to smooth manifolds. The fact is that rings of smooth functions behave poorly when you try and do algebraic geometry with them, because they actually have some deeper structure. If you want to properly apply algebraic geometry techniques to manifolds you should look at joyce’s book algebraic geometry over $C^\infty$ rings

@Chris, I don't see any use of cohomology here, since $H^0$ means simply the sections of the sheaf with respect to the appropriate topology (smooth, real analytic, complex analytic, algebraic).

There are two separate but closely related concepts of pullback here. There's the pullback of a sheaf (e.g., the sheaf $f^\Omega^n_Y$ over $X$) and, given a bundle map $E \rightarrow F$, where $E$ is a bundle over $X$ and$F$ is a bundle over $Y$, the pullback map from sections of $\Lambda^nF^$ to sections of  $\Lambda^nE^$. Here $E$ and $F$ are the tangent bundles and the bundle map is $f_: E \rightarrow F$ is the pushforward map.

There is a morphism of sheaves $ f^* \Omega_Y \rightarrow \Omega_X $ and that's exactly the pullback map.

@CraniumClamp Is there a good general description of this morphism in general? I'm aware of the relative cotangent exact sequence in the algebraic setting and the conormal exact sequence in the case $X$ is a closed subobject of $Y$ in either the analytic or algebraic setting, but I'm not aware of such a morphism for arbitrary smooth maps of real manifolds, for example.
